# JUnit test class with persistent, non-static field

Tags: junit, static, integration-testing

Straight forward question: in JUnit can I make a non-static field of a test class persist throughout the execution of each test method?

My goal is to be able to instantiate an expensive external resource only once over the execution of the entire test class, but due to our inheritance structure a static field with @ClassRule won't cut it.

I admit my question is against the principles of unit testing independence, and therefore may be impossible by definition.

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks SO!

Comment: Are you using Junit 4 or Junit 5? JUnit 5 introduced `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` which might help.

Comment: We're using 4.12
Don't see a reason we can't upgrade though, will try and get back.